# How to retrieve eigenvectors from shifted QR algorithm?

Tags: eigenvalues, eigenvector, numerical-linear-algebra

I understand that the key to retrieve eigenvectors in the non-shifted QR algorithm is to accumulate the transformations at each steps in the following way:

$Q = \Pi_i Q_i$

Can we accumulate the transformations in the same way when we are using the shifted QR algorithm?

$(A_i-\mu I) = Q_i R_i$

$R_i Q_i + \mu I = A_{i+1}$

If not, how can we retrieve the eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each step, the shifted and unshifted matrices, $A-\lambda I$ and $A$, have the same eigenvectors. So the diagonalizing transformation $A = Q D Q^T$, with $D$ diagonal, is accumulated in the same way as in the unshifted algorithm, $Q = Q_1 Q_2 \cdots Q_k$, where $k$ is the last step of the iteration.